# how to pass a map to function with keyword arguments

Tags: dictionary, clojure, parameter-passing

I have a function like this:

```
pdfkit-clj.core/gen-pdf
 [html & {:keys [path tmp asset-path stylesheets margin orientation page-size], :or {path (:path defaults), tmp (:tmp defaults), asset-path (:asset-path defaults), margin {}, orientation (:orientation defaults), page-size (:page-size defaults)}}]
```

Now I'm trying to pass it a map with keyword arguments which doesn't work.

```
(let [gen_pdf_args {:tmp tmp_dir
                     :margin {:top 0 :right 0 :bottom 0 :left 0}}] 
        (gen-pdf html-black gen_pdf_args)
)
```

This issue is similar to turning a list into arguments.

Comment: The first linked question has three different approaches to solving the problem; I agree with the top answer that the best approach is to stay out of this situation by not writing functions to take unrolled keyword args, but if you can't change the function's interface then I think the second linked question has the best answer for how to work around the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `& {:keys [...]}` actually doesn't expect you to call it with a map. Instead, you call it like `(gen-pdf html :tmp tmp_dir :margin {:top 0})`.

If you really want to use your map, you can use apply and flatten like `(apply gen-pdf html-black (-> gen_pdf_args vec flatten))`.

Comment: I understand that. I'm building up the arguments programmatically or I want to set arguments in one go.

Comment: See my edit. `apply` should solve your problem.

Comment: Yeah, I should use something light-weight for this instead of relying on external libs.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want something similar to the `keyvals` function:

```
(keyvals m)
 "For any map m, returns the keys & values of m as a vector,
  suitable for reconstructing via (apply hash-map (keyvals m))."

(keyvals {:a 1 :b 2})
;=> [:b 2 :a 1]
(apply hash-map (keyvals {:a 1 :b 2}))
;=> {:b 2, :a 1}
```

Notice that you still need to use `apply` like Alejandro said.  You can find more information on `keyvals` [here](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo#map-entries-key-value-pairs).

Comment: Yeah, this is good; just keep in mind that keyvals isn't part of core

Comment: Just use `(apply concat xs)` or `(mapcat seq xs)` instead of importing a whole big library to use `(keyvals xs)`.